# How can I create an object of fixed structure?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, revealing-module-pattern

I have the following code inside my revealing module, but I am uncertain with how to declare/define `imageListItem`, which is strictly a DTO and doesn't really require any information hiding. Am I correctly defining this object?

```
var imageListItem = function() {
    var _title;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "title", {
        get: function () { return _title; },
        set: function (value) { _title = value; }
        }
    );
};

var imageList = (function () {
    var buffer = new CBuffer();
    return {
        populate: function (listItems) {
            buffer.push(listItems);
        },
        rotate: function() {
             buffer.rotateLeft();
        }
    }
})();
```

With `imageListItem`, I want to declare an object structure for later use. That declaration should not logically be dependent on how that object will later be used. That is, I don't want to find myself dynamically assigning new properties to, or deleting properties from, `imageListItem` by accident. Any assignment to properties should strictly be only to properties that have already been declared on the object.

[`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) almost accomplihses this, by preventing properties being added or removed, but it also prevents properties being changed.

**E.g. I want this:**

```
var obj = {
  prop: function() {},
  foo: 'bar'
};

// New properties may be added, existing properties may be changed or removed
obj.foo = 'baz';
obj.lumpy = 'woof';

var o = Object.freeze(obj);

// Now any changes will fail
function fail(){
  'use strict';
  obj.delete(foo); // throws a TypeError
  obj.quaxxor = 'the friendly duck'; // throws a TypeError
}
```

**I dont' want this:**

```
// Now any changes will fail
function fail(){
  'use strict';
  obj.foo = 'sparky'; // throws a TypeError
}
```

You see? I want `freeze` to prevent `quaxxor` being added to `obj`, but I don't want it to prevent me changing the value of `foo`.

Comment: If you don't need any information hiding (or logic), why do you make it an accessor property? Just use `this.title = undefined;`.

Comment: (Not sure if that's the whole answer you are looking for)

Comment: @Bergi, it's probably close. I just didn't know how to declare an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Why is the property uninitialized at all? What code does actually create them?

Comment: @Bergi Nothing creates them except `this.title = undefined` or  `Object.defineProperty`. That is the point of my question - how to declare them.

Comment: No, I mean: What code calls `imageListItem`? What code uses the properties? Are they ever getting actual values beyond `undefined`, and how?

Comment: [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) ? or show the accident example.

Comment: @eicto @eicto `Object.freeze()` does what I want in preventing properties being added or removed, but I don't want to prevent properties being changed, as the Mozilla doc example shows it does. See my edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for may be either [**`Object.preventExtensions()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) or [**`Object.seal()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal).

Similarly to `Object.freeze()`, both methods **prevent new properties from being added to the object, nevertheless allow changing values of existing properties**.

The difference between `seal` and `preventExtensions` is that `seal` strictly disallows deletion and conversion of properties from/to data accessors, while `preventExtensions` doesn't actually prevent existing properties from being deleted: this behavior depends on the JS engine you're using (some engines may let you delete the property, other ones may not).

So basically, quoting from the MDN Documentation:

> The `Object.preventExtensions()` method prevents new properties from ever being added to an object (i.e. prevents future extensions to the object). [...] **Note that the properties of a non-extensible object, in general, may still be *deleted***.
>
> The `Object.seal()` method seals an object, preventing new properties from being added to it and marking all existing properties as non-configurable. Values of present properties can still be changed as long as they are writable. [...] **Attempting to delete or add properties to a sealed object, or to convert a data property to accessor or vice versa, will fail**.

Here's an example to demonstrate the behavior of both methods:

```
var myFirstObj = { foo: 1 },
    mySecondObj = { bar: "baz" };

Object.preventExtensions(myFirstObj);
Object.seal(mySecondObj);

myFirstObj.foo = false; // Works fine
mySecondObj.baz = "hello"; // Works fine
delete myFirstObj.foo; // May work fine depending on your JS engine

(function() {
    'use strict';
    myFirstObj.qux = 'something'; // Throws a TypeError
    mySecondObj.qux = 'something'; // Throws a TypeError
    delete mySecondObj.foo; // Throws a TypeError
})();
```

---

Now, talking about your `ImageListItem` Object, you can achieve what you want simply adding a line of code:

```
var ImageListItem = function() {
    var _title;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "title", {
        get: function () { return _title; },
        set: function (value) { _title = value; }
    });

    // Choose the one which fits your needs
    Object.preventExtensions(this);
    // or
    Object.seal(this);
};
```

Comment: the Mozilla page you link to says

"Note that the properties of a non-extensible object, in general, may still be *deleted*." I didn't specify that in my question, but it would be better to have and I'm adding it now. Yet your example suggests that a `delete` *wilI* fail. But `preventExtensions` is great to know about, thanks.

Comment: How is this not the correct answer? Above you just got through saying you wanted `preventing properties being added or removed`? I'd try for an answer, but your responses are far too fickle to attempt.

Comment: @ProfK I edited my answer adding what you needed, take a look at it :)